# Kubernetes 1.3 centos manual install

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to get kubernetes 1.3 intalled on my centos7 environment.  Have spent a terrifying amount of time looking at every doc/guide/tutorial out there, and unfortunately they are all a combination of outdated versions or missing instructions.

The two biggest issues:

- the RPM package is out of date. it pulls down 1.2, not 1.3
- which means i need to figure out how to install from source/tar, but i cannot find any good documentation out there on how to do that manually on centos7.

I have gotten it work installing 1.2, but have failed trying to upgrade 1.2 to 1.3 using the 1.3 tar.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Centos RPMs are maintained by volunteers, and it seems nobody has volunteered to build a 1.3 RPM.  The 1.2 RPM was generated by https://github.com/coolsvap.  You could try mailing him and asking him to make a 1.3 rpm.

The way you upgrade depends on which kubernetes guide you followed to setup your kubernetes cluster initially.   I'm not sure how it works on Centos guide.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this guide http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/ it mentions Kubernetes 1.4, so since this is a most recent version at the time of writing this post, this might be what you need.